# jQuery blur behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I want to listen `blur` event of every input field in the form, but when I reset the form after calculation, the again when i get focus of the input field it fires `blur` event two times, one with empty value and one with input value.

```
<form id="form">
    Total Ore to be Mined:
    <input type="number" name="TOmined" value="0" autofocus> Tons
    <br> Total Waste to be Mined:
    <input type="number" name="TWmined" value="0"> Tons
    <br> Number of Operating Days/Year:
    <input type="number" name="OperatingDays" value="0"> Days
    <br> Number of Operating Years:
    <input type="number" name="OperatingYrs" value="0"> Years
    <br>

</form>
<script>
    var arr = {};
    //  {"TOmined": inputValue}
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(":input").blur(function(e) {
            var k = e.target.name;
            var v = e.target.value;
            arr[k] = v;
            console.log(k, v); // **runs two times one with empty string**
            // one with original value 

        })
    });

    function calculate() {
        var sum = 0;
        // your logic
        console.log(arr);

        // end logic
        if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(arr)) {
            for (v in arr)
                sum += parseInt(arr[v]);
            console.log(sum);
        }
        $('#form').trigger("reset");
        //  $('#result').html(value to be displayed + ' tons/day');
        arr = {};
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How java comes into picture here ?

Comment: sorry, i wanted to add javascript. edited.

Comment: Highly recommend JSFiddle (and dropping unrelated JS) for these. Plugged in your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3ydL9bx/1/) but I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Might need to clarify what you mean by "when i reset the form"?

Comment: I am resetting the form in calculate function.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/L3ydL9bx/4/ i've edited the code. after the clicking the calculate 2nd time , observe the "arr" array in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way to spot the problem would be to add this line to your blur callback:

```
console.log(e.target);
```

... which will show you the element that was blurred. In this case, it's your `<button/>` element that is triggering a blur event. You're binding the blur callback to all `:input` elements, and `:input` is a jQuery extension that includes input, textarea, select, and button elements [(see documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

To fix this, you'll just want to bind to real `input` elements, not the `:input` selector.

```
$('input').blur(function (e) {
    // ...
});
```